# true require() for code rather than file

Tags: node.js

If I have a string with source code in it

```
var code = "console.log('I\'ve been loaded.');";
```

and want to run it in Node, normally it's suggest to use

```
vm.runInThisContext(code, "NOT_A_FILE.mycode");
```

This is all well and good until the code becomes more complicated:

```
var code2 = "require('http');\n" +
            "console.log(http);"  // TODO make more useless
```

In this case, we *cannot* run code2 in `vm` because it doesn't let the module have a `require()` function, as the vm is just a V8 VM, rather than a Node one.

This is the only problem I've run into so far—but I don't know what other problems may be down the road.

---

So, fundamentally, my question is: what extra functionality does `require()` do in making Node modules, and how can I ensure that  my "string" modules have this functionality? If I need this functionality, am I better off just making temporary files which I actually `require()`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This seems like a creative, but poor way to do something. If any of what you're essentially evaling is user generated you're inviting problems.

Comment: @RyanOlds I have a script which combines a lot of files together, and then tries to run the combined file. The source of the combined file is not useful (I have markers showing the original line numbers etc for debugging in the string).

Comment: Please let me know if code in my answer is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please `vm.runInNewContext` instead of `vm.runInThisContext`, then runs it in sandbox and you can pass require object ! Thats it..

```
var vm = require('vm');
var code2 = "var http = require('http');\n" + "console.log(http);" //TODO make more useless
vm.runInNewContext(code2, {
require: require,
http: require('http'),
console: console
}, 'yourvmfilename1');
```

OR you can directly send http object.

```
 var vm = require('vm');
 var code3 = "console.log(http);" //TODO make more useless
 vm.runInNewContext(code3, {
 http: require('http'),
 console: console
}, 'yourvmfilename2');
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that code run within require calls doesn't share its environment with rest of the code which means `require('http') instanceof Object` will be `false` etc...